# Google VM disappear from vm list but VM still accessible from SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Something strange happen on my Google Cloud Console.
One of my VM is missing from Google VM Instance list. However, It still active and accessible from SSH.
Is there any way to get detail such as name and project linked to it if I only have the public IP address of the VM instance.

Comment: Are you really able to SSH to the VM or just able to telnet ?

Comment: I'm able to SSH the machine. @norbjd

Comment: When you say "disappear" or "missing", I assume you didn't delete it, it just vanished? Is there an organization? If so, are there many projects in it?

Comment: No, I didnt not. if I delete the instance, I should not be able to SSH the machine.
yes, it just vanished from my VM list.

Comment: Do you know how to use the Google Cloud CLI? Compare with what you are seeing in the GUI. https://cloud.google.com/sdk

Comment: Can you please run this command and see if the output is your project id? ```curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the project id the VM belongs to, run the following command on the VM:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" \
 -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Refer to the following [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) to know more about setting and retrieving metadata.